# Is there a way I can paginate the included list in a linq query

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Hope you're doing well,

I was trying to optimize my reads with entity framework, where I arrived at a position, where I get a record from database by id, and I want to include a one-to-many related list, but I don't want to get all data of the list, just a few, so I want to kind of paginate it.

I want to do this process as long as data is in `IQueryable` state, I don't want to load all data of list in memory and that paginate it as enumerable.

Let's say the query is like below:

```
var author = await _dbContext.Authors.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                             .Include(x => x.Books) // <-- paginate this !!??
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Why don't you query Books instead? There is no need to start with Authors

Comment: I need author data too, imagine I have an author profile where I can see author's personal information and a few book he wrote

Comment: Do you mean that you only want authors with, say, max 5 of their books? If so, if this is EF-core 5+, you can use Skip/Take in Include.

Comment: yes I tried to paginate inside Include() method, as I remember I asked for author with 12 books, but it took for life to execute, so I thought it wasn't a good approach to go with.

Comment: Paging is a confusing word here because it's used for rendering pages of data to a front-end view where a user can "leaf through" the pages.  That said, if it takes a long time to get only 12 books then probably something is wrong altogether, like no indexes, too large records etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Entities represent Data state. Pagination and presentation concerns are View state. Entity Framework can help bridge that gap, but it does so by enabling projection so that you can build View state from Data state. *Don't* pass entities to views, instead build and pass ViewModels to represent the data in accordance to translations and limitations you want for the view.

For instance if you want to pass Author details with their 5 most recent books:

```
public class AuthorViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Any other relevant fields...

    public ICollection<BookViewModel> RecentBooks = new List<BookViewModel>();
}

public class BookViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
    // Any other relevant fields...
}

var author = await _dbContext.Authors
    .Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select( x => new AuthorViewModel
    {
       Id = x.Id,
       Name = x.Name,
       RecentBooks = x.Books
          .OrderByDescending(b => b.PublishedDate)
          .Select(b => new BookViewModel
          {
              Id = b.Id,
              Name = b.Name,
              PublishedDate = b.PublishedDate
          }).Take(5)
          .ToList()
    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

This gives you the benefit of structuring the data how you want to present it, while generating efficient queries against the database. You can configure tools like Automapper to perform this kind of mapping to use it's `ProjectTo<AuthorViewModel>()` as a more succinct alternative.